# Solution set of the linear equation $x + y - z = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

We took a quiz on linear algebra and I thought there might be a mistake regarding this provided question:

Which will be the solution set of the linear equation $x + y - z = 0$?

A. $z = t, y = s, x = t + s$ ; where $s$ and $t$ are any Real number

B. $z = t, y = s, x = t - s$ ; where $s$ and $t$ are any Real number

C. $z = t, y = s, x = -t + s$ ; where $s$ and $t$ are any Real number

D. $z = t, y = s, x = -t - s$ ; where $s$ and $t$ are any Real number

My answer is B but I was incorrect. Can someone explain why? I really believe B is the correct choice since if you solve for $x$, it will be $x = z - y$ or $x = t - s$. I will raise this concern in case I am correct, I just want to make sure.

Comment: It seems that you are right.

Comment: Yep, $x+y-z$ is A. $2s$, B. $0$, C. $-2t+2s$, D. $-2t$.